# Waiting for an event, but AT LEAST for a specified time

Tags: multithreading, delphi, events, delphi-10.4-sydney

Currently, I have come up with the following code:

Prerequisites:

```
CONST MinTime = 1000; // ms //
VAR ObjHandle : THandle := CreateEvent(NIL,TRUE,FALSE,'Event');
VAR T : LongWord;
VAR Signalled : BOOLEAN;
```

Code:

```
T:=GetTickCount; Signalled:=FALSE;
REPEAT
  CASE WaitForSingleObject(ObjHandle,MinTime) OF
    WAIT_OBJECT_0 : Signalled:=TRUE
  END
UNTIL Signalled AND (GetTickCount-T>=MinTime);
```

The aim of this code is to wait for an externally signalled event (from another thread), but only respond to this AT MOST once every second. Is this the proper way to implement this, or is there a more optimized (CPU-resource-wise) way of doing it?

Comment: I also make that mistake (`=` instead of `:=` in the new inline variable declarations). Of course, this is because we have been declaring constants this way for decades.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Ah, yes. That part of the code wasn't copy/pasted directly from my source, but added to clarify the prerequisites. I'll update it to := (BTW: How do you make text "grayed"? I know underscore makes italics, but gray?)

Comment: Greyed monospaced text is used for inline code. You use grave accents to accomplish this: `normal \`code\` normal` becomes "normal `code` normal".

Comment: Sounds like what you want is just a loop that checks once every second to see whether or not the event has happened.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Yes, but I want to use as little CPU time as possible, so how should this loop be implemented?

Comment: `Sleep` uses no CPU. However, its disadvantage is that it cannot be aborted. Say you have a thread that does `Sleep(5000)` every now and then. Fine -- no CPU wasted. But then the user wants to quit the application. If unlucky, that will take 5 seconds!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand "*`Sleep` uses no CPU. However, its disadvantage is that it cannot be aborted*" - [`SleepEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleepex) can be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 objects to wait on. One being the event. The other being a one-shot [waitable timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects) set to the desired sleep interval. Then use [`WaitForMultipleObjects()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) with `bWaitAll=TRUE` to wait for both objects to be signaled, no loop needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a problem whith the event. There are two options: auto-reset and manual-reset events [Look at Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/event-objects). With auto-reset event, when the `WaitForSingleObject` returns because the event is signaled, if the event if auto-reset will be reset and you'll loose the event.

You can either use manually-reset event and manage that your self (more complex) or once you grabbed the event and time from previous handling is too short, use a simple `Sleep` to wait the missing time.

Comment: Actually, my code is Manual Reset. But that's okay, as my `Signalled` is set on the first `WAIT_OBJECT_0` return, and stays set for the remainder of the loop. Later on, I simply check the `Signalled` variable to see if the event was fired during the second I'm looping around. An auto-reset would also work, but could result in a (nearly) 2 second loop, as it could set the `Signalled` variable after 0.99 seconds, then reset the event, then wait _another_ second for it to be set again.

Comment: Isn't `Sleep` CPU intensive? I started out by using `Sleep`, but I think I've read somewhere that one should use events instead to signal stuff like this (It's a queue I'm adding to from another thread that needs to be emptied occasionally, but I don't want to spend much CPU time when there's nothing added).

Comment: `Sleep` doesn't use any CPU, as you can very easily verify using the Task Manager. But one typically does not want to sleep a thread using `Sleep` *because it is not abortable*.

Comment: @HeartWare `Sleep` use almost no CPU. `Sleep` put the thread in suspended mode for the given duration. That's why event Sleep(0) has a lot of sense: It just stop the time slice allocated to the thread calling `Sleep`.

Comment: So, a `Sleep(1000)` followed by `IF List.Count>0 THEN` would be just as good (that was what I started with)?

Comment: @HeartWare Not exactly. You should take care of the time WaitForSingleObject has waited and substract that from the 1000mS you want. If result <= 0, proceed immediately, else sleep with that difference value.

Comment: @HeartWare You should mark my answer as accepted, if you accept it of course. If you don't, let me know what is not good for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an event for that.

Just use a variable, with a critical section if it should be thread-safe.

Something like:

```
var signal: boolean;

  signal := false;
  sleep(minTime);
  if signal then
  begin
    // do something
    signal := false;
  end;
```

Replace the `signal` boolean with whatever condition, like `if somelist.count>0 then`...